# Is it possible to outsource wp-admin to another server?

Tags: wp-admin, performance, server-load

This question might be very crazy and stupid, but I wonder if there is any chance that I could host the whole wordpress backend on another server, in order to minimize server load. For this, I guess, I should need two databases synced up, or do some load balancing?

I am asking this because, I just went to my admin page to check my stats and caused a huge spike on my server load. The site went down for a few seconds. Thank God, it didnt crash it.

I have between 400 to 500 users connected at the same time (Real-Time,Google Analytics). Most of them are logged out users, so no problem there. Logged in users have no access to the backend, just me.

Comment: What stats? If you are the only one with access to the backend it sounds like the problem is with bad code on the back end.

Comment: The jetpack stats. How can I find out if there is any bad code causing this?

Comment: Does the problem occur is you disable Jetpack? Or the Jetpack stats feature ( if that is possible)?

Comment: It is very difficult to replicate the issue. So I cannot try it by only disabling jetpack. Plus, if I disable and re-enable a plugin, the site might go down again for a few seconds and I cannot take that risk at this right moment due to the traffic I am receiving.

Comment: Then server logs?

Comment: If you can afford a second server just for admin, can't you afford to upgrade your main server?  Are you using any caching to ameliorate the load?